# ASP Classic Method to Extract City from Address String

Tags: asp.net

I am looking for a method to extract only the city from an address string in ASP Classic, is there a way I can do this, or resources i can read?

eg: C. del Esperanto, 17B, 03503 Benidorm, Alicante, Spain.
I want just Benidorm, the address strings will always be in the same format

Comment: Any reason you put the asp.net tag when asking about an ASP Classic question?  Also, looks like you have an answer, can you accept it if it is correct, or report back your results?

Answer (score 0):

Split on comma, then on the 3rd one (2 in the array), split on space, and take the second (1 in array)

Give this a try

```
addressSplit1 = Split(address, ",")

addressSplit2 = Split(addressSplit1(2), " ")

city = addressSplit2(1)
```